# How spi client driver is registered

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, fpga

I am new to Linux Device driver and trying to understand Linux device driver model which says a device must registered with its respected bus, be it the platform bus or real spi/i2c bus.

I could see the following macro which registered the i2c client device to its i2c bus.

```
module_i2c_driver(lm73_driver);
```

But I am not sure how it happen for a spi client device for example a CPLD/FPGA device sits on the spi bus.

Is such registrations based on the type of device?(block device or char device)

Comment: FPGA is not a CPU, it is a programmable HW, in order to have a SPI slave (not client) you need to instantiate or write your own SPI block that communicates to your host on one side and to the rest of your logic on the other side. If you do an internet search for SPI and FPGA you will find tons of examples and documents that will help you understand this, better than anything we can write in here.

Comment: Thanks FarhadA .I did try finding out some of resources related FPGA and SPI and I could find FPGA device access from user space access. I am specifically looking for a kernel module for FPGA/CPLD device and more so how SPI devices fits in device-driver model.How these devices registers with their respected spi bus.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you mean by "kernel model" here. Are you referring to access to the SPI interface on the FPGA via Linux kernel here? Or what?

Comment: Yes something like similar.Simply I have a FPGA/CPLD device sitting on spi bus then how do I write a driver for it keeping Linux device model in mind.

Comment: OK, what you need is a simple SPI driver for your CPU, that is a while different story. What CPU are you using? Is it a SoC? If you give more info, it will be easier to help you! This has nothing to do with the FPGA, you need to find out about your controller's SPI interface and a driver for it.

Comment: Yes it is a Soc with cortex A-15 CPU.Also,one more question direct to you.Can FPGA/CPLD device can host some more devices like UART/Watchdog?

Comment: Well of course, these are very simple IPs that almost all the FPGA can have resources to implement. But how you can access it from Linux on a CPU side is a whole different story.

Comment: Sorry @FarhadA,didn't get your first point "these are very simple IPs that almost all the FPGA can have resources to implement?

Comment: Well, I think you need to know what an FPGA is before asking these questions, here is a video to explain to you what FPGA is and what you can do with it in simple terms: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUsHwi4M4xE